# Remove HTML element from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML:

```
<td><span class="dott active green"></span> Firstname Lastname</td>
```

How can I remove this span via jQuery to get this:

```
<td>Firstname Lastname</td>
```

Comment: `$('td').html($('td').text())`

Comment: You didn't even bother to google "jquery remove element", did you? Otherwise, you would have noticed that the first result is [this](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Call `remove()` on the `span`, or set the `text()` on the `td` to it's current setting to remove the HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td id="myTd"><span class="dott active green"></span> Firstname Lastname</td>
```

```js
$('#myTd').find('span').remove();
```